# ExtJS Grid - scrolling shows large white space at the bottom/in the middle of grid

Tags: extjs, extjs7

**Issue description**

I have a paging-enabled grid with 100+ pages of data. Page size = 100 rows.

Even on page 1, if I drag the scroll box to the bottom of the grid, I see a large white space at the bottom of the grid.

Jump to page 30, and if I drag the scroll box to the bottom of the grid, I see a large white space at the bottom of the grid. If I drag the scroll box up and down the grid, I see flashes of large white spaces appearing in the middle of the grid as well (which are soon painted over with rows of data).

This does not provide a smooth scrolling experience to end users.

Picture showing [large white space at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEqGH.gif)

Picture showing [large white space in the middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1bmo.gif)

ExtJS version tried: 7.4.0

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

Here’s the fiddle to reproduce this issue:https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3e98

(1) On page 1, if you drag the scroll box to the bottom of the grid, you will see a large white space at the bottom of the grid.

(2) Jump to page 30, and if you drag the scroll box to the bottom of the grid, you will see a large white space at the bottom of the grid. If you drag the scroll box up and down the grid, you will see flashes of large white spaces appearing in the middle of the grid as well (which are soon painted over with rows of data).

Does anyone know why this issue occurs, and how to resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe something wrong with html in your json. Try can try to use column renderers for html and put in JSON only data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting "**variableRowHeight**" to true for any column that could have cells with varying heights.

To fix your example you can set it on these columns:

```
{
    text: 'CommandLineWithDisplayNames',
    dataIndex: 'CommandLineWithDisplayNames',
    flex: 3,
    variableRowHeight: true
},
{
    text: 'CommandLineWithNumbers',
    dataIndex: 'CommandLineWithNumbers',
    flex: 3,
    variableRowHeight: true
},
```

Documentation: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-variableRowHeight

Comment: Worked like magic! Thank you so much! I tested with several pages of data in our app and did not see the blank white space at the bottom of the grid on any of the pages! However, there is one minor issue, not sure if you have faced it:  Dragging the scroll box up and down really fast makes the scroll box go out of our control a little bit - the scroll box either lags behind the mouse, or the mouse pointer flies off the scroll box, is off to a side. This is a minor issue as we can grab the scroll box again and scroll as needed. Thanks for the help!